# how to get print() statements from a python script to show up in a text object in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to get a print statement from a different script to show up in tkinter GUI but i don't know where to start. does anyone know what to do? I've tried using a text object but couldn't do it. maybe I have to switch the print statements with return and do something with that IDk. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36604900/7432

Answer (score 0):

You first need to understand that print() outputs to the console, so that probably will not help you.

[tkinter text tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_text.htm)

Comment: I know this, I was wondering how I could make those print statements go into a tkinter GUI not the powershell.

Comment: console.log outputs to the browser (or IDE) console. I think you may need to go about this differently. But I am not an expert at tkinter.