# Terminal output to a text.insert tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, stdout

below 2 functions that I used to convert PDF 2 Docx, i am trying to get Terminal output into a text box or label, in the subprocess.Popen which command shall is start with?
thanks in advance.
Max

`

```
def directing():
    process = subprocess.Popen(['cv.convert'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,bufsize=1, text=True, shell=True)
    output = process.stdout.read()
    output = str(output).replace("b'", "").replace("\\n'", "")
     

def pdftodoc():
    #sys.stdout = text
    docx_file='' 
    Filepath = s1.get()
    cv = Converter(Filepath)
    cv.convert(docx_file, start=0, end=None)
    cv.close()
    text.insert('1.0',output)
```

`

Comment: You did not state what your problem is.

Comment: i want the Terminal output to be redirected or streamed to text or a label in my tkinter window, the output usually comes as [INFO] [3/4] Parsing pages... and so on, so when give the Popen the command of cv.convert is not recognized, ('cv.convert' is not recognized as an internal or external command)

Comment: The error tells obviously that `cv.convert` program or command cannot be found.  What do you want to execute actually? Or is it in those paths specified in env PATH? Can you execute the program in a console or terminal? directly?

Comment: yes i can with (PS D:\Lab> .\Converter3.py) in the Terminal, i want the pdf conversion process output to show in text

Comment: of course not it is part of pdf2docx

Comment: Then why do you execute it using `Popen()`?

Comment: how should I redirect terminal output or copy terminal output to text or label?

Comment: `cv.convert` cannot be executed by `Popen()`.  What you are asking is not possible.

Comment: So how can do it then? that's my question here

Comment: is it through sys.stdout.read()?

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604900/redirect-stdout-to-tkinter-text-widget) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Try polling the process

```
def directing():
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        ['cv.convert'], 
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        bufsize=1,
        text=True, 
        shell=True
    )
    while process.poll() is None: 
        output = process.stdout.read()
        output = str(output).replace("b'", "").replace("\\n'", "")
```

Comment: I did try it but it gave me error that no such process or command 'cv.convert'

Comment: Subprocess is used to run terminal commands in Python. I see now that `cv` is an instance of `Converter()`. Are you trying to run a terminal command, or are you trying to run `cv.convert` in a separate process?

Comment: i am trying to show the result of cv.convert that shows up in terminal to a label, usually the output that comes in Terminal is like that:

Comment: [INFO] Start to convert E:/RBASE/PDF/AccessToRBASE.pdf
[INFO] [1/4] Opening document...
[INFO] [2/4] Analyzing document...
[INFO] [3/4] Parsing pages...
[INFO] (1/16) Page 1
[INFO] (2/16) Page 2
[INFO] (3/16) Page 3
[INFO] (4/16) Page 4